# Surveymonkey: create webhook to get response in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm, webhooks, surveymonkey

I am trying to create a surveymonkey webhook to receive my survey response and i am passing my SugarCRM custom entry point URL as "Subscription Url". But i am getting error " 'mycustomEntryPointUrl' did not return a success status code. Status code is 301". My Entry point is working fine if i run it in browser using its URL also my Sugar is working smoothly. 
So, i just want to know any other reason which can cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes so HTTP status code 301 means the page has moved permanently. If you visit it in your browser, for example, you would see a network request to the page specified with a status code of 301, then a second one to the new page. Our API request won't do any redirect, so if a 301 is returned it will raise an error.

This sometimes happens when you go to a page with `http` and then it redirects to `https` due to rules on your server.

You also want to make sure your subscription URL supports a `HEAD` request without any redirect.